# button appearing differently on different android phones

Tags: android

I have a `linearlayout` with a background drawable, and a `button` in that `linearlayout` with no background set. The end result should look like this :

[image]

This works fine on my phone, however on my friends phone it looks like this :

[image]

I'm not sure what the issue is and I don't want it to look different once I publish the app on different phones. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Android :)
Different phones and android os versions can show views in different ways sometimes

Comment: Yes but there should be a reason behind this and a way to deal with it in code

Comment: You said in your phone it's working, so could you post the corresponding drawable code? or whatever you did to customize the button?

Comment: set background for this.

Comment: i think it is problem with drawable folder..

Answer (score 1):

Put background drawable in "res/drawable/" folder, and set background in button section.

I think you had to set background for any specific version only.

Comment: I have it already in the drawable folder. I didn't set the background for the button as I already have the layout behind it with the background I want.. If you notice, the other phone has all caps on the text for some reason too

Comment: Okay, All Caps and this type of background only display in 5.0+.

Comment: You need to customize this button.

Answer (score 0):

There are different layout files in the res/layout/ which can be automatedly taken for different devices of different display.
you can put in those respective folders and design different layouts for different type of display(xdpi,mdpi,hdpi etc).